# Drupal 6 with latest version php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

First of all, sorry to say I am not a PHP developer.

Recently I have migrated my all websites to a new shared server. All are working fine except one which is running with druapl 6 platforms. error like below

This page isn’t working drupal6.jshare.in is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I have searched a lot and most of saying that it is the issue related to the lower PHP version used in the Drupal 6, I would like to know any hack will help to use the compatible PHP version for this specific site only in my server. Please support.

Comment: You need to upgrade drupal site version to 7/8. Or need to check site with PHP version `5.6` rather than latest one.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Its really difficult to update to 7/8, any other solution/hack available?

Comment: You should try site with PHP version `5.6`. As per my knowledge, Every server will provide to select php version by sites as well.

Comment: Thanks, let me try!

Comment: Drupal 6 *can be made to work with PHP 5.6*, some contributed modules will need to be updated and/or patched.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6 support ends at the end of 2018 - in less than a month. But, Drupal 6 is still quite popular, and a company has created an update for D6 to run under PHP7.

The company offering the extended support is "one of two companies officially blessed by the Drupal Security Team (link is external) to do so."

You'll find release details here: https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/drupal-6-year-2020-and-php-7-support
... and a GitHub repo with the patches here: https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/tree/php-7

Comment: Drupal 7 it self will run nice on PHP 7, but lot of 3rd party modules won't. So if site is complex, with lot of contrib modules chances are big that some issue will occur. Downgrading PHP will save the site, for the moment, but eventually that solution will not be possible any more. Best one would be porting to D8.

Comment: Indeed. I had to go with PHP7.1 to keep some of our sites' modules working, though as you point out, even that will be too much in many cases. It looks like much of the Internet is very under-prepared for the death of 5.6 in less than two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Why I am posting my solution maybe it will help someone else.

As I am specified in my post I don't have experience in PHP.

So I have inspired the comment from @hardik_solanki, I had contacted the server team and they provide an option for setting the lower php version(5.6) for a specific website which is done with Druapl 6. It's sorted my issue.